# R data.table collapse and plot

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table)
DATA=data.table("X1"=sample(letters[1:3], 1000, r = T),
                "X2"=sample(letters[20:26], 1000, r = T),
                "X3"=sample(0:1, 1000, r = T))
```

I wish to leave the data in the format it is in but add a new column called "X1_COUNT" which for each letter equals to the total number of times that letter appears. So if "a" shows up in 300 rows then for every row that has "a" in "X1" I wish for "X1_COUNT" to be 300. Then I also wish to create "X1_COUNT2" which is the percent of "X1" = 'a' rows that have a '1' in "X3" so if there are 300 'a' in "X1" and among those 100 have a '1' in "X3" then I wish for "X1_COUNT2" to be 33.3 for "X1" equal to 'a'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add number of rows for each `X1` in `X1_COUNT` and calculate percentage of rows which have `X3 = 1`.

```
library(data.table)

DATA[, c('X1_COUNT','X1_COUNT2') := .(.N, mean(X3 == 1) * 100), X1]
#If X3 has only 1/0 can also use
#DATA[, c('X1_COUNT','X1_COUNT2') := .(.N, mean(X3) * 100), X1]
```

Comment: I think second line should be `DATA[, X1_COUNT2 :=  .N/X1_COUNT * 100]`

Comment: Thanks I think I had misread the question earlier. It should be ok now.

Comment: @RonakShah what if I wish to do exactly that and do it by X1 and X2? is it like this: by=list(X1,X2)] ?

Comment: Yes, that should work. You could also use `.(X1, X2)` which is the same.

Answer (score 2):

A tidyverse/dplyr way is also easy

```
DATA %>% as.data.frame() %>% group_by(X1) %>% 
  mutate(X1_count = n()) %>% group_by(X1, X3) %>%
  mutate(X1_count2 = n()*100/X1_count)

# A tibble: 1,000 x 5
# Groups:   X1, X3 [6]
   X1    X2       X3 X1_count X1_count2
   <chr> <chr> <int>    <int>     <dbl>
 1 c     y         0      366      52.5
 2 a     y         1      316      53.5
 3 a     u         0      316      46.5
 4 b     y         0      318      52.2
 5 a     w         1      316      53.5
 6 a     x         1      316      53.5
 7 a     x         1      316      53.5
 8 b     v         0      318      52.2
 9 b     t         1      318      47.8
10 a     y         1      316      53.5
# ... with 990 more rows
```